# Java map.containsKey doesn't work

Tags: java, dictionary

This might seem a simple question but I've been trying for a couple of hours now (without having to implement hashCode comparison) to make containsKey working. To simplify things I'll post a simple code example that i'm having issues with:

```
public class myPair {
private int a;
private int b;

    myPair(int x, int y) {
        a=x;
        b=y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object pair) {
        System.out.println("Ola");
        return true;
    }   


    int first()  { return a; }
    int second() { return b; }

    public String toString() {
        return "X: "+this.a + " Y:"+this.b; 
}
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Map<myPair,String> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<myPair, String>();
        myMap.put(new myPair(2, 2), "encontrou me");
        if(myMap.containsKey(new myPair(2, 2))){
            System.out.println(myMap.get(new myPair(2, 2)));
        }
        System.out.println(myMap.get(new myPair(2,2)));
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
null
```

I've implemented the equals method...why isn't it working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you *must* override `hashCode` in order to use a `HashMap` (or `LinkedHashMap`). That's just how hash maps work: They first compute the hash code to get a rough idea of where to look for the object. If the hash code does not equal the target objects hash code, it will simply look for the object in the wrong place!

This is from the API-documentation of `Object.hashCode`:

> - *If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object)  method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.*

The default implementation of `hashCode` will most of the times *not* return the same hash code for two distinct object.

Basically, you're violating the contract of the API by overriding `equals` but not `hashCode`.

Comment: Is there anyway to use a map structure without that?
and how could I implement it?

Comment: You could try another map implementation, such as `TreeMap` (but then your keys needs to be comparable). However, if you override `equals` you're violating the contract of the API if you're *not also* overriding `hashCode`.

Comment: Ok ill try to implement the hasCode member...thanks...how can I set this issue as solved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to also override the `hashCode` method as explained by [aioobe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276052/aioobe) and [hvgotcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305644/hvgotcodes).
Since `equals` is always returning `true`, the `hashCode` method must always return the same value:

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 123;    // qualquer número (any other number)
    }
```

but I doubt that an object with an `equals` method always returning `true` is very useful. At least notas a key for a map: there is no way to have more than one key-value pair in the map since there are no distinct keys. (maybe useful for testing)

Answer (score 0):

you need a hashCode method, and your equals method always returns true, which is incorrect.

Answer (score -4):

You can learn these concepts from the excellent book by Khalid Mughal and Rolf W Rasmussen. Its called SCJP.